# is it possible to make AG Grid custom cell editor with <input type="file"/>

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, html-input, ag-grid-react

I have some tasks to make custom cell editor for ReactJS AG Grid.
[link](https://www.ag-grid.com/)

is it possible to make custom cell editor with html file input?

```
<input type="file">
```

so users can select files like pictures and show it in the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use custom component in cell with some configurations like:

```
           <AggGrid
                .....
                onRowDragEnd={this.handleRowDrag}
                frameworkComponents={{
                    fileRenderer: FileUploadComponent
                }}/>
```

header Definition be like

```
[
 ...,
 {headerName: 'Attachment', field: 'file',minWidth: 100, cellRenderer: 
 'fileRenderer'},
...
]
```

this at your column named, `Attachment` with field file it will render `fileRender` where you provided `FileUploadComponent`.

Refer [Docs for FrameworkComponents](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/)

Comment: you can use onChange method of that component as usual and find other rowdetails on this.props

Comment: am I need REST API to do upload file?

Comment: It depends on you application need whether you want to upload file to server/filestorage or just show on screen. But whatever you want to do can be done over there at that component

Comment: okay, last question. if I just want store the image file in client-side where do I store that? react state?

Comment: you can either store base64 or path of file in state and render image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191651/discussion-between-revansiddh-and-necrofantaisie).